# Extract data from a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I currently have a custom `listview` with two rows of text in each item, one for the current time and one for the text the user inputs. I do this through creating a new `hashmap` and adding to the `<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` that the `listview` uses. I would like to save my data into the `sharedPreferences` but I only seem to be getting the last input from the user. My question is: is there anyway to extract the data from a listview then add it into the sharedpreferences? Or add the data in the arraylist into the sharedpreferences?

Here is my code below:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_feed);


            //create button and implement on click listener
            sendButton = this.findViewById(R.id.sendPostButton);
            sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            //create text field and add text change listener
            postTextField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.postTextField);
            postTextField.addTextChangedListener(TextEditorWatcher);


            //create text views for seeing the posts and character count
            currentTimeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postTimeTextView);
            mainPostTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postTextView);
            characterCountView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.charsleft);
            characterCountView.setText("150 chars left");

            //text view for event name and set the text
            feedName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameOfFeed);
            currentFeedName = CreateFeedActivity.eventFeedName;
            feedName.setText(currentFeedName);

            list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            //create the adapter for the list view
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    this,
                    list,
                    R.layout.post_layout,
                    new String[]{"time", "post"},
                    new int[]{R.id.postTimeTextView, R.id.postTextView});

            //set list adapter 
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            //place the current feed number into a variable here
            currentFeedCount = CreateFeedActivity.feedCount;

            //create the hashmap for the list view
            feedPostMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            //place the stored data into the view again if activity has already been created
            if (LiveFeedrHomeActivity.feedOccurs == 1){ 
                Log.d(TAG, "in feed occurs is 1");

                //get the shared pref
                sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MY_FEED, 0);
                Map<String, ?> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map = sharedPref.getAll();

                //convert from the map to the hashmap
                feedPostMap = (HashMap<String, String>) map;

                //add to the list
                list.add(feedPostMap);

                //refresh the adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.d(TAG, "feedmap get all");






            }

            //make variable feed = 1 so that you can't create another feed
            LiveFeedrHomeActivity.feedOccurs = 1;


     }

@Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
        switch(button.getId()){
        case R.id.sendPostButton:

            //create date
            date = new Date();

            //get current time
            currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aaa").format(date);

            SendToDatabase();

            DisplayUserInput();

            break;
        }



@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "on stopp'd");

        //get shared pref settings
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MY_FEED, 0);
        sharedPrefEditor = sharedPref.edit();



        //get the items in the hash map and add it to the 
        //shared preferences
        for (String string : feedPostMap.keySet()){
            sharedPrefEditor.putString(string, feedPostMap.get(string));

    //  }
        sharedPrefEditor.commit();



    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to store data in shared preferences? Is it security reason or you don't want to share it with others?

Comment: Well I am simply looking to store the items the user inputs in the `listview` so that when they return back to the current activity, the listview will be repopulated. I assumed sharedPreferences would be the way to go, but perhaps not? should I be saving the bundle or what do you recommend?

Comment: If you don't destroy your activity and just navigate to other then your data in listview remain as it is, so you don't need to use sharedPreference when you comeback to first activity onActivityResult() then your activity remain in same state. No need to create Activity again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is, this for loop,

```
for (String string : feedPostMap.keySet()){             
sharedPrefEditor.putString(string, feedPostMap.get(string));      
  }
```

so try,

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
   for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){      
       s.add(list.get(i).get(string));     
   } 

 sharedPrefEditor.putStringSet(stringSet, s);
```

Try this, for set of string to edit in sharedpreference,

```
putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)
```

**Set a set of String values in the preferences editor, to be written back once commit() is called.**

for more info look at [Android-SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Comment: I will try this out right now. Do I have to include `commit()` or the `apply()`?  Thanks a lot

Comment: also, what is the string set in `sharedPrefEditor.putStringSet(stringSet, s); `?

Comment: Ok, so i found out that `putStringSet` only works for API 11 and above. I am coding for API 8 and above. Any way to work around this? thanks.

Comment: for API 8 you have to store as a premitive data type as only String, So you have to store in many different keys and values.